# RxSwift, ViewModels and UI-bindings

Tags: swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I'm wondering what best practice is in the following situation:

- Project setup is Model-View-ViewModel
- I need to display a screen with text fields (e.g. `name`) where the user an edit details of a specific `Model`
- ViewModel contains an `Observable<Model>`; ViewModel is responsible for retrieving data from the API
- View contains input fields which need to be pre-populated with the current data from the `Model`
- Input fields need to be bound to e.g. `BehaviorRelay`s in the ViewModel

I am struggling with finding the best way to solve this:

- I don't want subscriptions in the ViewModel
- I want the ViewModel to be responsible for retrieving the data and populating the `BehaviorRelay`s or similar

I basically want to have something similar to `BehaviorRelay`s, but with an initial value from an `Observable`. Upon subscription (binding) to the BehaviorRelays, I want them to retrieve the data from the API. Or `flatMap` an `Observable` to a `BehaviorRelay`?

What would be the best way to solve this?

The ways I've implemented this before, with their drawbacks:

1. Skip the `BehaviorRelay`s in the ViewModel, and keep the state in the ViewController. Just subscribe from the ViewController to the `Observable<Model>` in the ViewModel and bind it to the UI. Then when the user wants to save the data, retrieve the latest value from the UI (`withLatestFrom()`) and pass it as a value to a `func save(attribute: Value)` in the ViewModel. This works, but I'd like to keep all the state (and business logic) in the ViewModel.
2. In the ViewModel, use `BehaviorRelay` with an empty initial value, then in the `init()` of the ViewModel, retrieve the data and bind it to the `BehaviorRelay`s. This means having a subscription in the ViewModel, which I want to avoid.
3. Having something like a `func refresh() -> Completable` in the ViewModel, which sets the values in the `BehaviorRelay`s in its `do(onNext:)`. This works but feels hacky.
4. Having a `let refresh = PublishSubject<()>()` in the ViewModel, and e.g.

   ```
   var model: Observable<Model> {
     refresh
       .startWith(())
       .flatMapLatest { retrieveData() }
   }
   ```

   again, with a `do(onNext:)`. Same drawback as previous solution (feels hacky).
5. Retrieve the data before initializing the ViewModel, and initialize the ViewModel with the model instance. I don't like this solution as I want the ViewModel to be responsible for retrieving it's own data.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

My first point would be that I think you need to think a little bit more about the role of a ViewModel in MVVM.   The purpose of the viewmodel is to transform/modify the data from the model in such a way that it is perfectly suited for display on *that screen*.   As such, if you are making a screen full of editable fields, then the ViewModel should be splitting the data up into those discrete fields.  In Rx, this would typically mean exposing an Observable(or Driver if you want) for each field.  The goal is to make the binding of each property in the viewmodel *simple* for the View.  The view shouldn't be doing any presentation transformation/logic, that belongs in the VM.

You are correct that your VM should not be making any subscriptions, the ViewController (View in MVVM) will make the subscriptions to each of the fields it's displaying.   You can have the viewmodel use `.share()` on the call to the API and use that resulting observable to feed each of the field observables so they aren't all each making their own call to the API when the view subscribes to them.

I'm not sure what you are referring to by needing a BehaviorRelay.  Perhaps you can clarify what the need is there.  If it's because you want a way to trigger a refresh then your 4th bullet makes the mose sense.  You could set it up like this

let fetchDataTrigger = PublishRelay();

```
let dataModelObservable = fetchDataTrigger.asObservable()
    .startWith(())
    .flatMap {
        return goCallMyApi()
    }
    .share()
```

and then each of your properties could transform the output of `dataModelObservable` to produce that field's value.  If you wanted to trigger a refresh you simply call `fetchDataTrigger.accept(())` in response to your button push or whatever triggers a refresh.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I indeed transform the data in my ViewModel for direct usage in the View, but kept the example simple for brevity. Why I want to use BehaviorRelays is because I want to do a two-way binding between the BehaviorRelay in the ViewModel and the UITextField in the ViewController.

Comment: I still dont see why you need a BehaviorRelay.  What should the behavior be when a user changes a textfield?  Does it send something back to the server?   If so you can call `fetchDataTrigger.accept(())` when you change the value of that field in the viewmodel (and server) by calling a method in the VM to do just that.   

Another important aspect to Rx is working with unidirectional immutable data.  Always assume that data moving from the API towards the UI is immutable and unidirectional.  If you need to modify something, then it should result in another event in that flow to update the UI

Comment: Maybe I'm just misunderstanding something, but let's say we have a screen for editing a user profile. Then I'd have a EditProfileViewModel which contains a `let name = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")`. From the UI I bind this, e.g.: `let nameTextField = UITextField()` and `nameTextField.rx.text.bind(to: viewModel.name)`. Then in the ViewModel, I have a `func save() -> Completable` which gets the current values from the BehaviorRelays and posts them to the API. This works for a new user profile, but for existing users, the UITextField need to be pre-populated with the current value.

Comment: Use `flatMapLatest` for network calls instead of `flatMap`.

Comment: Ok if you want to maintain a "state" you could use the observable from each field in the UI (e.g. textField.rx.text) and add `distinctUntilChanged().replay(1)` and set those into your viewModel.  Then when you want to send data to the server you can zip all of those up, transform it for the API and send it.

Comment: @RutgerBresjer I have similar issue (although in my case, I'm not doing any two-way binding). I have a `BehaviorRelay` in view model. I also have something so called "initial observable" that makes API request when view model is initialized. I want to assign that value to `BehaviorRelay` but no one subscribes to that observable. How did you manage to solve this?